# bibliography errors

Tags: biblatex

I am about to start writing my thesis in latex, but seem to have some trouble implementing bibliography. In the simple document below, I am just practicising the basics. But I seem to keep failing at implementing bibliography in the document. I keep getting the (blue colored) errors 'Citation Schoen2013 on page 6 undefined', 'Empty bibliograph' and 'there were undefined references'. I created a document 'literature.bib' in notepad++ and saved in the folder 'bib'. The .bib document has the content below. Any ideas?

```
@article{schoen2013,
author  = {Torsten Schoen and Co Author},
title   = {Ten things you better not say to your wife},
journal = {Optimizing Husbands},
volume  = {21},
year    = {2013},
pages   = {85--91},
 }

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\addbibresource{bib/literature.bib}
\begin{document}[a4paper,12pt]

\chapter*{Declaration}

\chapter*{Abstract}

\chapter*{List  of abbrevations and symbols}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Insurance industry}

\includegraphics{fig/circle}

\section{IBNR Claims and Claims Reserving}

\section{Link with GLM}

 We refer to \cite{schoen2013}

\section{Robustification and Problems}

\section{Applications}

\chapter{Body}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you run `biber`?

Comment: Did you run Biber? See [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) (although you might not see a question mark, but a **bold** version of the cite key) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have carefully gone through the explanation. So if I am right, my code is correct but I need to run biber? I think I do this by pressing f11, no? Because the error does not dissapear

Comment: Your code should work fine, but you have to run Biber (in fact you have to run at least a sequence of `pdflatex test`, `biber test`, `pdflatex test`, `pdflatex test`). How Biber is run depends on your editor, see the second question I linked to there. You can always use the command line directly.